# Multiple sum queries from same table and multiple where conditions

Tags: mysql

I have 2 queries that i want to put into one and then GROUP BY fName.
I tried hundreds of times but i cant get it to work.

```
 SELECT fName, code, 
 SUM(totalOr) AS totOr
 FROM person
 WHERE code = '4'
 GROUP BY fName

 SELECT fName, code, 
 SUM(totalPl) AS totPl
 FROM person
 WHERE code = '1'
 GROUP BY fName
```

Comment: You need conditional aggregation.

Comment: how do you want them to be put into one- side by side (i.e., each row contains both totOr and totPl) or one below the other (each row contains one total column)?

Comment: Yes i know, i tried but cant get it to work. If the where col was same as the sum col its easy but this i dont understand.

Comment: I want it side by side per person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE` statement

```
SELECT 
    fName,
    code,
    SUM(CASE WHEN code = 1 THEN totalOr ELSE 0 END) AS totOr,
    SUM(CASE WHEN code = 4 THEN totalPl ELSE 0 END) AS totP1
FROM
    person
WHERE
    code IN ('1' , '4')
GROUP BY fName, code;
```

Answer (score 1):

you should first join the table with itself, and then sum it up:

```
SELECT o.fname, 
       o.code, 
       Sum(o.totor) AS totOr, 
       Sum(p.totpl) AS totPl 
FROM   person o 
       INNER JOIN person p 
               ON o.fname = p.fname 
                  AND o.code = 4 
                  AND p.code = 1 
GROUP  BY o.fname
```